# Set custom widow duration for Pub/Sub to Text Files on Cloud Storage dataflow from GCP console

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to implement [Pub/Sub to Text Files on Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-streaming#cloudpubsubtogcstext) dataflow template from GCP console with custom window duration like 1hr instead of 5min(which is default).

Any suggestions would be of great help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Through the GUI, it seems impossible. However, if you use directly the [template on github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/PubsubToText.java) you have a parameters for this.

The rollout of the new versions could be done soon, but in case of emergency, you can use directly the Java code.

Answer (score 0):

Since it was already mentioned, when using Dataflow [Google-provided](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-templates) templates it is not possible to change the pipeline parameters that are different to introduced [runtime](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-templates) ones, you might consider for the particular *Pub/Sub to Cloud Storage Text* template either:

- Clone the template [source](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/PubsubToText.java), integrating it in your own local Beam
  project and adjusting the customization for the required default parameters:

  ```
   @Default.String("1h")
   String getWindowDuration();
   void setWindowDuration(String value)
  ```

or

- Cloning the source pipeline code and predefine the runtime parameter
  for window duration in the ValueProvider [interface](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates#runtime-parameters-and-the-valueprovider-interface):

  ```
  ValueProvider<String> getWindowDuration(); void
  setWindowDuration(ValueProvider<String> value);
  ```

Comment: when I am trying to go with 2nd option in your answer (using ValueProvider).I am getting below exception due to below code inside run() method of pipeline when trying to construct pipeline.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Value only available at runtime, but accessed from a non-runtime context: RuntimeValueProvider{propertyName=windowDuration, default=null}
pipeline.apply(options.getWindowDuration() + " Window",
             Window.into(FixedWindows.of(DurationUtils.parseDuration(options.getWindowDuration().get()))))